# Item is not a constructor when instantiating as a string

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to create an instance of an object, but I am getting:

> TypeError: window[comps[i]] is not a constructor

It is happening in this method (in the for loop):

```
private getComponents() {
    let comp = this._element.getAttribute('component');
    if (!comp) {
        comp = this._element.getAttribute('data-component');
    }
    let comps = comp.split(' ');
    for (let i = 0, l = comps.length; i < l; i++) {
        this._components.push(new window[comps[i]]());
    }
}
```

This is the class that it is trying to instantiate, but is not

```
class TestComponent extends Component {
    public click() {
        alert('you clicked me');
    }
}
```

The component class then looks like this:

```
class Component {

    public constructor() {

    }

}
```

Comment: what does `getAttribute('component')` return ?

Comment: It returns `TestComponent`

Comment: did you try to add `public constructor() { super(); }` to `TestComponent` class ? Also, you don't need to add `public` to `constructor` function

Comment: Maybe you need add `TestComponent` to window object? `window.TestComponent = TestComponent;`

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Component {
    constructor() {
      console.log('Component created');
    }
}

class TestComponent extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
    }
  
    click() {
        alert('you clicked me');
    }
}


this._components = new Array();

getComponents();

function getComponents() {
  // note TestComponent not 'TestComponent'
    let comps = [TestComponent];
  
    for (var i = 0; i< comps.length; i++) {
      this._components.push(new comps[i]);
      this._components[i].click();
    } 
}
```